# Why is @angular/core/core has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'. error thrown when build the project?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, bitbucket

I have my global Angular CLI version (13.0.1) and the local version in the project is (10.2.3).
All things was good, I did some change in some components **(I didn't touche package.json)** and when I run my pipeline (bitbucket pipeline)  I get in the build step this error :

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop/ngx-file-drag-drop.component.d.ts:45:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
45     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop/ngx-file-drag-drop.component.d.ts:46:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.
46     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropComponent, "ngx-file-drag-drop", never, { "disabled": "disabled"; "multiple": "multiple"; "displayFileSize": "displayFileSize"; "borderColor": "activeBorderColor"; "accept": "accept"; "emptyPlaceholder": "emptyPlaceholder"; }, { "valueChanged": "valueChanged"; }, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/byte.pipe.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
7     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<BytePipe, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/byte.pipe.d.ts:8:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵPipeDeclaration'.
8     static ɵpipe: i0.ɵɵPipeDeclaration<BytePipe, "byte">;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
10     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule, [typeof i1.NgxFileDragDropComponent, typeof i2.BytePipe], [typeof i3.CommonModule, typeof i4.MatChipsModule, typeof i5.MatIconModule, typeof i6.MatTooltipModule], [typeof i1.NgxFileDragDropComponent, typeof i2.BytePipe]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
11     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.1 build: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T17_41_21_825Z-debug.log
```

I reproducte this error locally when I run my project, but it still! despite I delete node-modules, package-lock.json. also the problem still while I switch to a branche doesn't containts the new changes and I delete node-modules, package-lock.json.

**error :**

```
+ npm run build
> client@1.0.1 build /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client
> ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false
Warning: Entry point 'ngx-highlightjs' contains deep imports into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight.js'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngrx/store : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-translate/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling angular-in-memory-web-api : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-perfect-scrollbar : module as esm5
Compiling ng-inline-svg : module as esm5
Compiling ngx-permissions : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngrx/effects : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngrx/router-store : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngrx/store-devtools : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngrx/entity : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-loading-bar/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-markdown : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-captcha : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-mask : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material-moment-adapter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-highlightjs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-select/ng-select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-textarea-autosize : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-autosize : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling angular2-text-mask : main as commonjs
Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/fire : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/fire/firestore : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-dropzone : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/textarea : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/core/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/multicheckbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-formly/material : es2015 as esm2015
WARNING in Entry point 'angular2-text-mask' contains deep imports into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/text-mask-core/dist/textMaskCore'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop/ngx-file-drag-drop.component.d.ts:45:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
45     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop/ngx-file-drag-drop.component.d.ts:46:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.
46     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropComponent, "ngx-file-drag-drop", never, { "disabled": "disabled"; "multiple": "multiple"; "displayFileSize": "displayFileSize"; "borderColor": "activeBorderColor"; "accept": "accept"; "emptyPlaceholder": "emptyPlaceholder"; }, { "valueChanged": "valueChanged"; }, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/byte.pipe.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
7     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<BytePipe, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/byte.pipe.d.ts:8:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵPipeDeclaration'.
8     static ɵpipe: i0.ɵɵPipeDeclaration<BytePipe, "byte">;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
9     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
10     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule, [typeof i1.NgxFileDragDropComponent, typeof i2.BytePipe], [typeof i3.CommonModule, typeof i4.MatChipsModule, typeof i5.MatIconModule, typeof i6.MatTooltipModule], [typeof i1.NgxFileDragDropComponent, typeof i2.BytePipe]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop/lib/ngx-file-drag-drop.module.d.ts:11:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/new-client/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
11     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<NgxFileDragDropModule>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.1 build: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T17_41_21_825Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you checked the version of `ngx-file-drag-drop`? It seems that this library requires a higher Angular version than you're currently using

Comment: The version is `ngx-file-drag-drop": "^5.1.0`, and before it was good I didn't change nothings.

Comment: Check the installed version because ^ means each compatible version can be used/installed by npm, so maybe you've a newer version installed which causes this error

Comment: You can see that in the package.json in `node_modules/ngx-file-drag-drop` or with `npm list ngx-file-drag-drop`

Comment: The version is `5.1.3` so is different . what i should do ?

Comment: Removing the `^` in your package.json and reinstall `node_modules` could solve your issue

Comment: It solved the issue, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `^` character from `ngx-drag-drop` library in package.json, because I had `"ngx-file-drag-drop": "^5.1.0"` so the version installed was `5.1.3` not `5.1.0`. to get more information about the character `^` see [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: Thanks, in my case, the package names were different. So, I removed `^` from all the dependencies which were complaining.

Comment: @munir mounir are you opne for some UI work? can you please share your email